# Did the Venom symbiote inhabit the Hulk?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, the-incredible-hulk, venom

In the Marvel Comic universe, the Venom symbiote used Peter Parker as a host, thus learning Spider-Mans abilities. So when Venom later was hosted by Eddy Brock, they were able to do *whatever a spider does* - so to speak.

In the game LEGO MARVEL Super Heroes, you can unlock Venom as a playable character. In that game however, Venom has the ability to transform into a Hulk-like figure, similar to the fashion in which Bruce Banner can transform into the Hulk.

Venom transforming into a hulkish figure would imply the venom symbiote inhabiting Bruce Banner at some point.

Which characters *did* the Venom symbiote infect in the Marvel comic canon? **Was Bruce Banner ever host to the Venom symbiote?**

[image: Spidey-Venom and Hulk-Venom side by side]

Comment: Venom has inhabited dozens of characters within the various comic (not even to mention the film and TV canons). This stands on the edge of being a "list" question...

Comment: @Richard You are right, I changed the emphasis to Bruce Banner to make it less list-ish. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, in the [What If... comic](http://marvel.wikia.com/What_If%3F_Vol_2_4); "What If the Alien Costume Had Possessed Spider-Man?" we see Venom possessing the Hulk. Note that the outfit worn by Venom/Hulk is basically identical to that seen in the Lego game and could easily have served as the inspiration.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok... I need to know what happens in that comic.

Answer (score 8):

In the mainstream Marvel continuity (Earth-616), the Venom symbiote has never been bonded to Bruce Banner.

However, in the 2012 [Circle of Four](http://marvel.wikia.com/Circle_of_Four) storyline, the Venom symbiote was temporarily passed from [Flash Thompson](http://marvel.wikia.com/Eugene_Thompson_(Earth-616)) to [Red Hulk](http://marvel.wikia.com/Thaddeus_Ross_(Earth-616)), who was also fused with the [Spirit of Vengeance](http://marvel.wikia.com/Alejandra_Blaze_(Earth-616)) at the time:

[image: Venon/Red Hulk/Ghost Rider]

### Other continuities

- In "Hulk and the Agents of S.M.A.S.H." (Earth-TRN123), Doctor Octopus created a [specially-modified variant of the Venom symbiote](http://marvel.wikia.com/Gamma_Venom_(Symbiote)_(Earth-TRN123)), with the intent of creating a "venomized hulk". This variant temporarily possessed Skaar (Hulk's son), She-Hulk, Red Hulk, A-Bomb, and the Hulk himself before being destroyed.
- The original Venom symbiote possessed Hulk in the Anime [Marvel Disk Wars: The Avengers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Disk_Wars:_The_Avengers)

Comment: Wow. Red Hulk with the powers of the symbiote AND Ghost Rider. Yeah, that's not OP at all.

Comment: Hulk was also possessed by a Carnage symbiote in an episode of "Ultimate Spider-Man".